# Turn Windows 7 Start Menu "Shut Down" button into "Log Off" even when Windows Updates are pending

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows

I've configured our Windows 7 clients to have "Shut Down" replaced with "Log Off" as the default button on the Start Menu in the labs on our campus using Loopback and

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar\Change Start Menu power button
```

The problem is that if there are Windows Updates pending, this changes back to Shutdown and I don't see a way to alter this behavior. I would like it to always be "Log Off" regardless of whether or not updates are pending.

AD is at a 2008R2 DFL and FFL and third party templates aren't an option, but additional Microsoft templates not included by default are fine.

Comment: Do you have anything configured under `Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Update` `Do not display 'Install Updates and Shut Down' option in Shut Down Windows dialog box`?

Comment: @jscott - It's not configured. Will enabling that change the Start Menu power button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to deal with some of these settings when I set up a WSUS server. For whatever reason, not all start menu options are in the start menu configuration. Go to the path below in your gpediter (local or system wide)

```
Computer Configuration\admin templates\windows components\windows update then look for "Do not display 'Install Updates and Shut Down' option in shut down windows dialog box"
```

Change that value to disabled and it should fix it.